# Typescript abstract method doesn't inherit the params type

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
abstract class Foo<T extends { data: string }> {
  abstract doSomething(params: T): void;
} 


class Baz extends Foo<{ id: string; data: string }> {
   doSomething(params) {}
}
```

My expectation is that when implementing the `doSomething` method it'll automatically infer the `params` as `T`, but it infers it as `any`. Am I wrong?

Comment: I think this relates to general problem with function argument inference. From my experience,  TS is able to validate function arguments. I mean, if you provide invalid argument type - TS will complain about it but, unfortunately, TS is unable to autocomplete the type

Answer (score 0):

By extending, the compiler just checks whether the derived class is assignable to the base class, you are free to design the derived class as long as it is assignable to the base class.

Imagine you are not extending, just writing a regular class. `doSomething(param)` does implicitly means `doSomething(param:any)`. This implication dose not change even when you are extending. Since `(any) => void` is assignable to `({ id: string; data: string }) => void` , everything is fine. The compiler won't do extra work.